# Date time not formating in AngularJs 1.6

Tags: angularjs

I've got this format of date coming from an api:

```
"dateTime": "2018-02-19 00:00:00.000-08:00"
```

I just want the days, month and year in the format: `dd/MM/yyyy`

I'm using this in the view:

```
<td>{{dado.dateTime | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

But it's shows the date extacly as it comes from the API. Without any formatting

**OBS: Angular 1.6**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `T` in your original DateTime. For [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) DateTime it should be `"2018-02-19T00:00:00.000-08:00"` as the value. That is what can be translated by the angular [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) as a `DateTime`, currently it can only be interpreted as a `string`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) on the input:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

---

If you do not have any control over the server/source then you have a couple of options:

1. Change the value of the date time string in the factory/service when you receive the data so it is [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant. This can be as simple as using a regex or string concatenation as long as the `T` character is added between the date and time. In this specific case you could take the first 10 characters as you probably want to completely ignore the time portion but that would not work where you do want to show or keep time as a part of the datetime.
2. Create your own filter that then calls through to the built in date filter once you format the input correctly.

Comment: I don't have control over this data...is coming from an API using `http.get` can I format this in the view somehow?

Comment: @IgorMartins - You have some options, see my update.

Comment: Thanks...I don't know how to do any of them..i'll try